# GitHub: Failed to Sync

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a project that is being worked on by multiple people. I can manually push changes with command prompt but when I am trying to sync repositories on my GitHub Desktop i receive this message:

```
Sync failed: The repository doesn't seem to exist anymore. You may not have
access, or it may have been deleted or renamed.
```

I have checked and it has not been removed or renamed, i don't understand the not have access part and i cant find any information about it.

I just want to confirm that i can push and pull using GitBash but it will not Sync when i use the Sync button on the Desktop application but i can commit changes.

Comment: Is it a private or a public project?

Comment: @AntonSizikov It is a private project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the reason was that my SSH key at Github was unused for a while so it got unverified. If you run git push on the command line, it clearly tells you this error, whereas the Desktop is rather vague.

```
ERROR: We're doing an SSH key audit.
Reason: unverified due to lack of use
Please visit https://github.com/settings/keys to
approve this key so we know it's safe.

Fingerprint: xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

You can go to https://github.com/settings/keys/ and re-enable any keys that got unverified.